# Using Vue, how can I remove elements from the screen after they have been deleted?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am learning Vue, and I have a list of todo items that has a checkbox that I am able to mark as complete. Everything in my application is working.

When I check the checkbox, I am adding items to the `completedItems` array. When unchecked, I am removing items. I am able to check the array length and it is also correct.

I have a button that I can click that will remove all items marked as complete from my list.

The overarching logic is working fine. The status of being marked as complete is working, and the actual record is getting deleted as expected.

However, I am unable to remove the item from the actual view. I am not sure what I am doing wrong -- incorrectly updating my `completedItems` array or something. The items that I delete will only disappear after a full page refresh.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<task v-for="item in list.items">...</task>




...
data() {
    return {
        completedItems: [],
    }
},
props: ['list'],

...

axios.delete(...)
.then((response) => {
if (response.status === 204) {
    this.completedItems = this.completedItems.filter(i => i !== item);
} else {
    console.error('Error: could not remove item(s).', response);
}).catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
});
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here is how I am checking for a match now, and it is coming across correctly, the element in the array still isn't getting removed from the page.

```
this.completedItems = this.completedItems.filter(i => i.id !== item.data.id); 
 // i.id = 123
 // item.data.id = 123
```

Comment: If “item” is a complex object, you can’t compare via === or similar inside filter(). You need to compare a specific property such as id or some other unique identifier to filter out.

Comment: It is... I can have multiple lists. From each list, I can mark any item as `completed`. I will experiment using specific values. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: The concept does work with the mechanisms you're using. I've made a simplified example that might help: https://jsfiddle.net/e840y6of/.

Comment: Ah - I think I see the problem. I am passing in my original `list` as props.  `props: ['list'],` Then looping over that.

So, to remove the item from the screen I need to update the original list passed in as a prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid manipulating props directly, since props are supplied by the parent component and can be changed without notice.  I would do something like this:

```
data(){
    return{
        completedItems[],
        localList: this.list
    }
}
```

Then, manipulate and bind the `localList` array instead of the prop, this should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped get me pointed in the right direction. Thank you everyone for their suggestions!